# Error: Requested Resource Too Large to Return [responseTooLarge] (trying to import a google bigquery table in R)

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I am able to import a table of dimensions: 468 by 905 in R but when I try to import a table with dimension 5000 by 905, I get this error in R:

Error: Requested Resource Too Large to Return [responseTooLarge]

Here is the code:

```
billing <- "project_id" 

con <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "project_id",
  dataset = "dataset_name",
  billing = billing,
  use_legacy_sql = FALSE,
  allowLargeResults = TRUE
)
```

```
project<- "project name"
sql<- "select * from `table_name`"
data <- dbGetQuery(con,sql,use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
```

Comment: GBQ TO R LARGER DATA SETS, this worked!

data<- bq_table_download(bq_project_query(
  project,
  query = 'select * from `table_name`'),
  bigint = 'integer64',
  page_size = 1000) 
dim(data)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are hitting the maximum response size limit in [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#jobsquery_requests). In [github site](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/a3ef603f36495bc13d9a5f5081010084bf3c146c/R/bq-download.R#L35-L37) of the project, you can find following advise about using `page_size` property:

> @param page_size The number of rows returned per page. Make this
>   smaller if you have many fields or large records and you are seeing a
>   'responseTooLarge' error.

For reference, you can read through this [Bigrquery manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/bigrquery.pdf) (page 8).

You can also try to use another method, which allows for download BigQuery dataset to R (page 18 in manual).

```
bq_table_download(tb, max_results = 10)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

GBQ TO R LARGER DATA SETS, this worked!

```
data <- bq_table_download(bq_project_query(
  project,
  query = 'select * from `table_name`'),
  bigint = 'integer64',
  page_size = 1000) 

dim(data)
```